fail to start service on fedora os
I need run program in Fedora OS after boot.
I create service file in:
/etc/systemd/system/muxponder.service
File looks like this:
[Unit]
Description=Your Program Description

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root  # This will run the program as root
ExecStart=/etc/systemd/system/hello.exe

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

After enabeling:
systemctl enable service_name.service
I restarted OS, getting following error:
Apr 13 15:33:28 fedora (ello.exe)[741]: muxponder.service: Failed to locate executable /etc/systemd/system/hello.exe: Permission denied
Apr 13 15:33:28 fedora (ello.exe)[741]: muxponder.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/systemd/system/hello.exe: Permission denied
The executable exist:
[root@fedora system]# file /etc/systemd/system/hello.exe
/etc/systemd/system/hello.exe: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=d775638b8c4b716700be21202b1684bd05b6239e, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
Not sure what wrong, any suggestions. Thanks

Is the binary executable. I.e. does it have x-bits when you do ls -l /etc/systemd/system/hello.exe?
(It is quite odd to put an executable in that directory. /usr/local/sbin would be more natural. And it is not common to have any suffix on executables in the Unix world. exe is a Windows specific suffix.)

I haven't checked, but there might also be selinux policy preventing executables from running from that directory.  (And if there isn't, maybe there should be!)
